# Creating a function with generic type with ScalaPB

Tags: scala, generics, scalapb

I have the following function (which works on a protobuf object MyRequest

```
  def createRequestFromJson(requestJson: String): MyRequest = {
    val protoJson = getResource(requestJson)
    JsonFormat.fromJsonString[MyRequest](protoJson)
  }
```

I want to reuse this function with a different object so I added a type

```
  def createRequestFromJson[A](requestJson: String): A = {
    val protoJson = getResource(requestJson)
    JsonFormat.fromJsonString[A](protoJson)
  }
```

but then I get an error

```
Error:(68, 30) type arguments [A] do not conform to method fromJsonString's type parameter bounds [A <: scalapb.GeneratedMessage with scalapb.Message[A]]
JsonFormat.fromJsonString[A](protoJson)
```

I tried changing the definition to

```
  def createResponseFromJson[A <: scalapb.GeneratedMessage with scalapb.Message[A]](protoJsonFile: String): A = {
```

but still gives more errors

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`JsonFormat.fromJsonString` needs an implicit `GeneratedMessageCompanion`. It would work if you change the signature to:

```
def createResponseFromJson[A <: scalapb.GeneratedMessage with scalapb.Message[A]
     : GeneratedMessageCompanion](protoJsonFile: String): A
```